# bitbake: adding php-intl support to php recipe

Tags: php, yocto, icu, bitbake, openembedded

I need to build a php package supporting the intl extension with bitbake (http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php).

So I created a bbappend:

```
bernardo@bernardo-UX51VZA:~/dev/yocto/meta-steempi$ cat recipes-devtools/php/php_7.%.bbappend 

DEPENDS += " icu apache2"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += " icu apache2"

PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-php = " apache2 icu icu-dev"
EXTRA_OECONF += " --with-openssl=${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${exec_prefix} \
                  --with-config-file-path=${sysconfdir}/php/apache2-php${PHP_MAJOR_VERSION} \
                  --with-icu-dir=${BASE_WORKDIR}/${MULTIMACH_TARGET_SYS}/icu/60.2-r0/image/usr \
                  --enable-intl \
"
```

To enable the intl compilation, I added the **--enable-intl** and **--with-icu-dir** to **EXTRA_OECONF**.
However, the configure task presents the following error, even though the path to **icu-config** was added to **--with-icu-dir**.

```
...
| checking whether to enable internationalization support... yes
| checking for location of ICU headers and libraries... not found 
| configure: error: Unable to detect ICU prefix or /home/bernardo/dev/yocto/poky/build-qemux86-64/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/icu/60.2-r0/image/usr/bin/icu-config failed. Please verify ICU install prefix and make sure icu-config works.
| NOTE: The following config.log files may provide further information.
| NOTE: /home/bernardo/dev/yocto/poky/build-qemux86-64/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/php/7.2.4-r0/build/config.log
| ERROR: configure failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/bernardo/dev/yocto/poky/build-qemux86-64/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/php/7.2.4-r0/temp/log.do_configure.19483)
ERROR: Task (/home/bernardo/dev/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/php/php_7.2.4.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1802 tasks of which 1801 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/bernardo/dev/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/php/php_7.2.4.bb:do_configure
Summary: There were 2 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

I suspect the configure is trying to find icu's headers, because the **icu-config** script (generated by icu recipe) is set with the right path.

When I try to add icu-dev to the DEPENDS variable in my bbappend, I get

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'icu-dev' (but /home/leprechaun/dev/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/php/php_7.2.4.bb DEPENDS on or otherwise requires it). Close matches:
  udev
  icu RPROVIDES icu-dev
ERROR: Required build target 'php' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['php', 'icu-dev']
```

When I try to add icu-dev to the RDEPENDS variable in the bbappend, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'icu-dev-native' (but virtual:native:/home/leprechaun/dev/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/php/php_7.2.4.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target 'icu-dev-native' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['icu-dev-native']
ERROR: Required build target 'php' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['php', 'php-native', 'icu-dev-native']
```

Any ideas on how to get out of this hole?

Thanks!

Comment: Some comments. You can replace `PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-php` by  `PACKAGECONFIG_append` as you are already in php recipe. `DEPENDS` is for recipes, so it will not work with `icu-dev` as it is a package. `RDEPENDS` will put dev package to your running target, it's not what you want. php provides native package, so it checks for icu-dev-native package, that does not exists. Maybe you'll have to patch icu-config to work with Yocto cross-compilation. Did you look at errors in `config.log` file?

Comment: Be careful as packageconfig exists for apache2 `PACKAGECONFIG[apache2] = "--with-apxs2=${STAGING_BINDIR_CROSS}/apxs,,apache2-native apache2"` so you can maybe add `PACKAGECONFIG[icu2] = "--enable-intl --with-icu-dir=${STAGING_BINDIR_CROSS}/icuXX,,icu2-native icu2"`

Comment: hey @Nayfe thanks for the reply... I'll add a few comments addressing each topic

Comment: I checked `poky/meta/recipes-support/icu/icu.inc`:

`# ICU needs the native build directory as an argument to its --with-cross-build option when
# cross-compiling. Taken the situation that different builds may share a common sstate-cache
# into consideration, the native build directory needs to be staged.
EXTRA_OECONF = "--with-cross-build=${STAGING_ICU_DIR_NATIVE}"
EXTRA_OECONF_class-native = ""
EXTRA_OECONF_class-nativesdk = "--with-cross-build=${STAGING_ICU_DIR_NATIVE}"`

so I guess no patch is needed for icu-config... right? I'm not 100% sure on this one

Comment: sorry the comment section merged the lines from `icu.inc`, but I guess you can get the picture

Comment: If I replace `PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-php` by `PACKAGECONFIG_append` I get the following error:

https://paste.debian.net/1022225/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and took me a while but I got the php build working. This is my .bbappend file:

```
EXTRA_OECONF_append_class-target = " --with-curl=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.."
DEPENDS_append_class-target = " icu curl"

EXTRA_OECONF =+ " --enable-mbstring --with-openssl --enable-bcmath --enable-sockets --enable-intl \
                                          --with-icu-dir=${BASE_WORKDIR}/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/icu/62.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr \
                      , \
                      , icu-native icu"
PACKAGECONFIG ??= "sqlite3"
PACKAGECONFIG[sqlite3] = "--with-sqlite3=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.. \
                          --with-pdo-sqlite=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.. \
                          , \
                          ,sqlite3"

LIBS_pn-php =" -lpthread "
export LIBS
THREADS_pn-php = "pthread"
export THREADS
```

## Update  - 01-01-2020

Something is wrong with the PHP 7.2.1 recipe. If you you are on "thud" branch for your layers then you might want to either switch to "warrior" branch and re-run the `bitbake php -v` command or copy the recipe for php 7.3.x + files to your php recipe directory from here https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/tree/master/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/php.

Also, you could just use the PACKAGECONFIG option.  Your mileage will vary to the third party libs you want for your php build. I got php intl working on both thud and warrior branches using the following updated recipe for PHP 7.3.4:

```
EXTRA_OECONF_append_class-target = " --with-curl=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.."
DEPENDS_append_class-target = " icu curl openssl"

EXTRA_OECONF =+ " --enable-mbstring --with-openssl=${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${exec_prefix} --enable-bcmath --enable-sockets --enable-intl \
                      , \
                      , icu-native icu"
PACKAGECONFIG ??= "intl sqlite3"
PACKAGECONFIG[sqlite3] = "--with-openssl=${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${exec_prefix} \
              --with-sqlite3=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.. \
                          --with-pdo-sqlite=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.. \
                          , \
                          ,sqlite3"

LIBS_pn-php =" -lpthread "
export LIBS
THREADS_pn-php = "pthread"
export THREADS
```