# Enable php intl extension in Yocto

Tags: php, yocto

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54066288/881712) I put in `meta-custom-layer/recipes-devtools/php/php_%.bbappend` file the this content:

```
PACKAGECONFIG_pn-php = "mysql sqlite3 imap opcache openssl ${@bb.utils.filter('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'ipv6 pam', d)} apache2"

EXTRA_OECONF_append_class-target = " --with-curl=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.."
DEPENDS_append_class-target = " icu curl"

EXTRA_OECONF =+ " --enable-mbstring --with-openssl --enable-bcmath --enable-sockets --enable-intl \
                  --with-icu-dir=${BASE_WORKDIR}/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/icu/62.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr \
                        
                  , \
                  , icu-native icu"
PACKAGECONFIG ??= "sqlite3"
PACKAGECONFIG[sqlite3] = "--with-sqlite3=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.. \
                          --with-pdo-sqlite=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.. \
                          , \
                          ,sqlite3"

LIBS_pn-php =" -lpthread "
export LIBS
THREADS_pn-php = "pthread"
export THREADS
```

but after `bitbake icu` under `${BASE_WORKDIR}/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/icu/62.1-r0` there's only a `temp` folder with all the icu tasks, but no `recipe-sysroot-native`. I also tried to `bitbake build-sysroots` with no changes.

Hence, `bitbake php` fails because it doesn't find the expected files in that folder.

### UPDATE

Here the error message:

> checking for location of ICU headers and libraries... not found
>
> configure: error: Unable to detect ICU prefix or /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/icu/62.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/icu-config failed.

I found `icu-config` here:

```
work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/crossscripts/icu-config
```

but because it tries to append `/bin`to the path set on `--with-icu-dir` I'm not able to tell it where to find `icu-config`.

### UPDATE2

After following the hints of @Jussi Kukkonen I get these weird compile errors:

```
cc1: warning: include location "/usr/include" is unsafe for cross-compilation [-Wpoison-system-directories]
cc1: warning: include location "/usr/include" is unsafe for cross-compilation [-Wpoison-system-directories]
In file included from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/Zend/../TSRM/TSRM.h:52,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/Zend/zend_portability.h:49,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/Zend/zend_types.h:27,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/Zend/zend.h:29,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/main/php.h:35,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/ext/intl/dateformat/../php_intl.h:23,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/ext/intl/dateformat/dateformat_format.c:21:
/usr/include/pthread.h:681:6: warning: 'regparm' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
      __cleanup_fct_attribute;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pthread.h:693:3: warning: 'regparm' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
   __cleanup_fct_attribute;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pthread.h:716:6: warning: 'regparm' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
      __cleanup_fct_attribute;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pthread.h:729:3: warning: 'regparm' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
   __cleanup_fct_attribute;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pthread.h:738:6: warning: 'regparm' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
      ;
      ^
cc1: warning: include location "/usr/include" is unsafe for cross-compilation [-Wpoison-system-directories]
In file included from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/Zend/../TSRM/TSRM.h:52,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/Zend/zend_portability.h:49,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/Zend/zend_types.h:27,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/Zend/zend.h:29,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/main/php.h:35,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/ext/intl/php_intl.h:23,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/ext/intl/dateformat/dateformat_parse.c:24:
/usr/include/pthread.h:681:6: warning: 'regparm' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
      __cleanup_fct_attribute;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pthread.h:693:3: warning: 'regparm' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
   __cleanup_fct_attribute;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pthread.h:716:6: warning: 'regparm' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
      __cleanup_fct_attribute;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pthread.h:729:3: warning: 'regparm' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
   __cleanup_fct_attribute;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pthread.h:738:6: warning: 'regparm' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
      ;
      ^
In file included from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/Zend/../TSRM/TSRM.h:52,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/Zend/zend_portability.h:49,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/Zend/zend_types.h:27,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/Zend/zend.h:29,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/main/php.h:35,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/ext/intl/php_intl.h:23,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/ext/intl/msgformat/msgformat.c:24:
/usr/include/pthread.h:681:6: warning: 'regparm' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
      __cleanup_fct_attribute;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pthread.h:693:3: warning: 'regparm' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
   __cleanup_fct_attribute;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pthread.h:716:6: warning: 'regparm' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
      __cleanup_fct_attribute;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pthread.h:729:3: warning: 'regparm' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
   __cleanup_fct_attribute;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pthread.h:738:6: warning: 'regparm' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
      ;
      ^
In file included from /usr/include/math.h:472,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/ext/intl/dateformat/dateformat_parse.c:22:
/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/php/7.2.10-r0/php-7.2.10/ext/intl/dateformat/dateformat_parse.c: In function 'zif_datefmt_parse':
/usr/include/bits/mathinline.h:751:3: error: invalid 'asm': invalid operand for code 'w'
   __asm __volatile ("fnstcw %3\n\t"           \
   ^~~~~
/usr/include/bits/mathinline.h:503:5: note: in definition of macro '__inline_mathcodeNP_'
     code;              \
     ^~~~
/usr/include/bits/mathinline.h:746:1: note: in expansion of macro '__inline_mathcodeNP'
 __inline_mathcodeNP (floor, __x, \
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/bits/mathinline.h:769:3: error: invalid 'asm': invalid operand for code 'w'
   __asm __volatile ("fnstcw %3\n\t"           \
   ^~~~~
/usr/include/bits/mathinline.h:503:5: note: in definition of macro '__inline_mathcodeNP_'
     code;              \
     ^~~~
/usr/include/bits/mathinline.h:764:1: note: in expansion of macro '__inline_mathcodeNP'
 __inline_mathcodeNP (ceil, __x, \
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:463: Error: bad instruction `fnstcw [sp,#16]'
{standard input}:464: Error: bad instruction `movzwl [sp,#16],r3'
{standard input}:465: Error: bad instruction `andl $0xf3ff,r3'
{standard input}:466: Error: bad instruction `orl $0x0400,r3'
{standard input}:467: Error: ARM register expected -- `movw ,[sp,#18]'
{standard input}:468: Error: bad instruction `fldcw [sp,#18]'
{standard input}:469: Error: bad instruction `frndint'
{standard input}:470: Error: bad instruction `fldcw [sp,#16]'
{standard input}:685: Error: bad instruction `fnstcw [sp,#16]'
{standard input}:686: Error: bad instruction `movzwl [sp,#16],r3'
{standard input}:687: Error: bad instruction `andl $0xf3ff,r3'
{standard input}:688: Error: bad instruction `orl $0x0800,r3'
{standard input}:689: Error: ARM register expected -- `movw ,[sp,#18]'
{standard input}:690: Error: bad instruction `fldcw [sp,#18]'
{standard input}:691: Error: bad instruction `frndint'
{standard input}:692: Error: bad instruction `fldcw [sp,#16]'
Makefile:1007: recipe for target 'ext/intl/dateformat/dateformat_parse.lo' failed
make: *** [ext/intl/dateformat/dateformat_parse.lo] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Function failed: do_compile
```

Comment: Pretty much every line in that snippet is somehow weird but the main thing is that the icu-additions just can't work like that: it looks like PACKAGECONFIG format but used in EXTRA_OECONF (with a hard coded build host path to boot). You should probably be adding a PACKAGECONFIG[icu] (similar to the sqlite3 one) assuming php really needs the path spelled out. I can take a quick look assuming the php build doesn't take forever...

Comment: icu-config is a red herrring: those almost never work in cross-compilation situations so they are typically not even made available in yocto. pkg-config would work (because there's a special version in Yocto) but for some reason that would be too easy and projects like php don't seem to use it.

Comment: @JussiKukkonen my Yocto knownloedge is too little to full understand your hints. Basically I need to enable the `intl` php extension to run CakePHP applications. If there's a simpler way I'm glad to learn it!

Answer (score 1):

So here's how I'd try to do it (I'm not a php specialist and the build seems to take such a long time that I'm not testing this on target myself). The following creates a new packageconfig

```
PACKAGECONFIG[intl] = "--enable-intl,--disable-intl,icu"
```

php actually supports pkg-config so it should just find icu with that. At least configure works fine here on Yocto Warrior: php finds icu and enables intl.

With that addition you can then add "intl" to your PACKAGECONFIG line (and remove "_pn-php" postfix: it is not useful inside the recipe file or bbappend):

```
PACKAGECONFIG = "intl mysql sqlite3 imap opcache openssl ${@bb.utils.filter('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'ipv6 pam', d)} apache2"
```

You should also be able to remove that EXTRA_OECONF monstrosity. While you're at it maybe remove all of the sqlite3 lines unless you know you really need them (they are in all maintained yocto versions already as far as I can tell). So remove these:

```
EXTRA_OECONF =+ " --enable-mbstring --with-openssl --enable-bcmath --enable-sockets --enable-intl \
                  --with-icu-dir=${BASE_WORKDIR}/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/icu/62.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr \

                  , \
                  , icu-native icu"
PACKAGECONFIG ??= "sqlite3"
PACKAGECONFIG[sqlite3] = "--with-sqlite3=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.. \
                          --with-pdo-sqlite=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.. \
                          , \
                          ,sqlite3"
```

To tell you the truth none of the remaining lines seem useful either but maybe they're not actively harmful.

Comment: As a comment: Yocto and the recipe format can be overwhelming at first. Blindly copying stuff is not a good strategy to deal with that (I'm speaking from experience here). I suggest doing one modification at a time and making sure it does what you thought it does (by bitbaking and looking at logs, build results and sysroots inside WORKDIR)

Comment: In the meanwhile I'm try to follow your hint - I agree with you. The difficult I face in learning Yocto is that a lot of stuff seems "magical". It's a programming language after all, and should be clear rules about "how to do" things.The docs just tell what every single bit does, but not how to put all toghether.

Comment: Just to be sure: would you please confirm in which file I should place the lines above? `meta-custom-layer/recipes-devtools/php/php_%.bbappend` ?

Comment: Unfortunately it fails... question updated with logs.

Comment: the log indicates that headers from /usr/include get used during compile -- these are your build host headers so not correct, it should use headers in the sysroot. This may be a bug in the build system of the intl-part of php (or somehow the recipe is giving wrong paths to the build system). Careful reading of compile logs ($WORKDIR/temp/log.*) and the build system files is the only thing I can suggest

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with the PHP 7.2.1 recipe. If you you are on "thud" branch for your layers then you might want to either switch to "warrior" branch and re-run the `bitbake php -v` command or copy the recipe for php 7.3.x + files to your php recipe directory from here https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/tree/master/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/php.

Also, Jussi Kukkonen is correct in that you could just use the PACKAGECONFIG option.  Your mileage will vary to the third party libs you want for php, but I think the issue here is the recipe.  I got php working on both thud and warrior branches using the following:

```
EXTRA_OECONF_append_class-target = " --with-curl=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.."
DEPENDS_append_class-target = " icu curl openssl"

EXTRA_OECONF =+ " --enable-mbstring --with-openssl=${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${exec_prefix} --enable-bcmath --enable-sockets --enable-intl \
                      , \
                      , icu-native icu"
PACKAGECONFIG ??= "intl sqlite3"
PACKAGECONFIG[sqlite3] = "--with-openssl=${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${exec_prefix} \
              --with-sqlite3=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.. \
                          --with-pdo-sqlite=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.. \
                          , \
                          ,sqlite3"

LIBS_pn-php =" -lpthread "
export LIBS
THREADS_pn-php = "pthread"
export THREADS
```